# How does pandas.grouped.apply( ) decide on output, and why does this depend on whether some groups return None?

Tags: pandas

I'm a little mistified by the behaviour of grouped.apply(). The type of res1 and res2 are different. res1 is Series and res2 is DataFrame. Can someone explain the rationale?

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    def exampleFrame():
        animal = ['Tiger','Lamb','Pony']
        sizeCat   = ['Tiny','Small','Medium','Large','Huge']
        nPeriods  = 150
        D         = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=nPeriods)
        T         = np.random.choice( animal , nPeriods )
        S         = np.random.choice( sizeCat, nPeriods )
        P         = np.cumsum( np.random.randn(nPeriods) )
        df        = pd.DataFrame( {'Price':P,'Animal':T,'Size':S,'Days':D} )
        df.set_index( ['Days'], inplace = True)
        return df

    def sometimesNone(grp):
        if np.random.choice( [True, False] ):
            return grp.iloc[0]
        else:
            return None

    def neverNone(grp):
        return grp.iloc[0]                                

    df   = exampleFrame()
    res1 = df.groupby(['Animal']).apply( sometimesNone )
    res2 = df.groupby(['Animal']).apply( neverNone )
    print res1.__class__
    print res2.__class__
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for 0.12. This is fixed on master/0.13, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5592)

Return a Series that is like-indexed instead of None. The return logic is quite complicated, but essentially tries to find the like-indexed in the returns from the function. This is pretty easy if they are Series/Frames. But if its a scalar their is not indication of the index; it primarily looks to the first return value which could be misleading (in general its not, but in this case it is).

In any event, you can return a like-indexed object instead to get consistent results.

```
In [82]: def f(x):
   ....:     if np.random.choice([True,False]):
   ....:         return x.iloc[0]
   ....:     return Series(index=x.columns)
   ....: 

In [83]: df.groupby('Animal').apply(f)
Out[83]: 
        Animal  Price  Size
Animal                     
Lamb       NaN    NaN   NaN
Pony       NaN    NaN   NaN
Tiger      NaN    NaN   NaN

[3 rows x 3 columns]

In [84]: df.groupby('Animal').apply(f)
Out[84]: 
       Animal     Price  Size
Animal                       
Lamb      NaN       NaN   NaN
Pony      NaN       NaN   NaN
Tiger   Tiger -0.297888  Tiny

[3 rows x 3 columns]

In [85]: df.groupby('Animal').apply(f)
Out[85]: 
       Animal     Price   Size
Animal                        
Lamb      NaN       NaN    NaN
Pony     Pony  0.249086  Small
Tiger     NaN       NaN    NaN

[3 rows x 3 columns]

In [86]: df.groupby('Animal').apply(f)
Out[86]: 
       Animal     Price   Size
Animal                        
Lamb     Lamb -0.533083   Huge
Pony     Pony  0.249086  Small
Tiger   Tiger -0.297888   Tiny

[3 rows x 3 columns]

In [87]: df.groupby('Animal').apply(f)
Out[87]: 
       Animal     Price  Size
Animal                       
Lamb     Lamb -0.533083  Huge
Pony      NaN       NaN   NaN
Tiger   Tiger -0.297888  Tiny

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Consistent with a previously troubling  observation that grouped.apply( ) actually calls the function on the first group twice. Presumably the first pass is to check the type, and for clarity (or laziness) it doesn't bother to reuse the first result.

Comment: the calling twice is to determine whether the function mutates the group. if it does pandas takes a different (slower) path. No way around that one. FYI, you can use ``.first()`` on the groupby to get the first row of every group (and its faster). you can then do another operation (say ``.filter()`` to decide which groups to returns; in general much faster than using a custom function.